# SceneKit is crashing due to memory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

so im working on a 3D application on iOS using SceneKit. Everything is working fine, untill I started to implement larger and more files. Now it crashes like every 4-5th time i restart the scene from my main viewcontroller. After a few tests i found out it was the memory that was too full after a few restarts. (and yes the restarts are needed to change from one 3D file to another) So im starting my scene, after that im including my referenceNode with the model that is shown.

When the scene starts:

```
if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "compressed", ofType: "dae", inDirectory: "models.scnassets") {
        let referenceURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            referenceNode = SCNReferenceNode(url: referenceURL as URL)!
            referenceNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y:0, z:0)
            referenceNode.load()
            gameScene.rootNode.addChildNode(referenceNode)
        }
    }
```

When im exiting the scene and try to unload every node:

```
        gameScene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) -> Void in
        node.geometry = nil // tried didnt change anything.
        node.removeFromParentNode()
    }
        referenceNode.removeFromParentNode()
        referenceNode.unload()
```

I tried other solutions I´ve seen on the web which told me to use:

```
node.geometry!.firstMaterial?.normal.contents = nil
node.geometry!.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = nil
```

Which returned me:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Im pretty much running out of ideas right now. Also if i check for existing nodes after reloading the scene, it returns that there are none. So does anyone have an idea how i could be able to get those files out of the memory?

Comment: Found out why. Instead of using the dismiss function due to a push, I initiated another push, which caused the controller to stay up in the background. Casual beginner mistakes :/

Comment: You should post an answer to your own questions and added the details of how you found the issue and how you fixed it.